# What is 'User Time' in web page speed tests?

Tags: performance, page-speed

I am running a few tests on my site's speed using https://webpagetest.org.

I noticed a metric in there called 'User Time'. Tried Googling and looking through the site documentation but could not find anything on this metric.

Is this the perceived user load time?

Would anyone know what it means?

[image]

Comment: It looks like they have a forum that has answered this question: https://www.webpagetest.org/forums/showthread.php?tid=12993